# Perl requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# countlines2.pl by Bill Weinman <http://bw.org/contact/>
# Copyright (c) 2010 The BearHeart Group, LLC

use strict;
use warnings;

sub main {
my @values = (43,123,5,89,1,76);
my @values1 = sort(@values);

  foreach $value(@values1){
    print "$value\n";
  }
}

Errors - 
"Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at task2.txt line 12
"Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at task2.txt line 13
```

I am beginner in perl so i am having the above errors. Also please do tell me how the perl sorts the numbers by default(e.g. what the sort(@values) will result in?).

Comment: The error message makes no sense with respect to the actual problem.

Answer (score 17):

You might find it helpful to add `use diagnostics;` which would give you this additional information:

> (F) You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates
>   that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my" or
>   "state"), declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to
>   say which package the global variable is in (using "::").

`foreach $value(@values1){` should be `foreach my $value(@values1){`

Answer (score 11):

The error is because you are not declaring `$value`:

```
foreach my $value(@values1){
    print "$value\n";
  }
```

The sorting documentation can be found here: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html.